# Is there a replacement for Times Roman that has Unicode math symbols and Greek letters?

Tags: fonts, xetex, unicode

Another program (pandoc) is generating `.tex` files that are loaded with Unicode math symbols and Greek letters.  I am successfully using those files with `xelatex`, but with the default fonts, it is hard to get math symbols and subscripts.  The only "mainstream" serif font I have found that supports all these symbols is `DejaVu Serif`.  But it looks *very* different from the Times New Roman that I have been using for all my other documents.

Is there another font, more closely approximating Times New Roman, that has extensive Unicode support?  I have tried `Tinos` and `Liberation Serif` with no luck.

Here is a minimal non-working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{STIX} % subscripts are missing
% \setmainfont{DejaVu Serif} % subscripts are present
\begin{document}
I want x₁ ↦ τ₂.
\end{document}
```

With STIX, I get the math symbol, but not the Unicode subscripts. What font can do both, and looks mostly like Times Roman?

Comment: There are many, I think, but it's hard to guess which to recommend given the details in the question. What about [New TX](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/newtx/) or [Stix](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/stix/) or [Xits](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/xits/)? And have you looked at [The LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/)?

Comment: stix especially stix2 is designed as a times-inspired font for math

Comment: I have looked at the Catalogue, but I don't know how to read it to tell which fonts support Unicode subscripts.  I will see if I can download New TX and Xits and report back.

Comment: you want stix2 not stix but I assumed you were generating math  markup, but  I think stix2 has the subscripts (it has a lot more text rather than math glyphs, stix 1 was more of a math companion font to go alongside times

Answer (score 4):

[STIX Two](http://www.stixfonts.org) Math has (almost) full coverage for upright text; you can use it together with the STIX Two Text fonts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{STIX Two}[
  UprightFont={* Math},
  ItalicFont={* Text Italic},
  BoldFont={* Text Bold},
  BoldItalicFont={* Text Bold Italic},
]

\begin{document}

I want x₁ ↦ τ₂.

\textit{Italic τ₂}

\textbf{Bold τ₂}

\textbf{\textit{Bold Italic τ₂}}

\end{document}
```

Math specific characters are of course missing from the Text fonts.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Stix2 has separate text and math fonts, but the math font may be enough:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{STIX2Text-Regular.otf} 
\setmainfont{STIX2Math.otf} 

% \setmainfont{DejaVu Serif} % subscripts are present
\begin{document}
I want x₁ ↦ τ₂.
\end{document}
```